# Using Securimage's PHP Captcha script in a 508 accessible application

Tags: php, captcha, section508

I’m setting up a Contact-Us page and we’ve picked Securimage’s PHP Captcha script for blocking robots. Securimage uses a Flash object to play the captcha code for someone who may be visually impaired. On Securimage’s demo page, the Flash object doesn’t show up when I look at the page with the Fangs screen reader emulator. It appears that a visitor to the site that’s using a screen reader would know there’s a captcha code required, but they wouldn’t be able to hear the code in order to enter it. We are looking to be accessible.

Is there a way to make the Flash object show up in a screen reader and is there a way to add a title that says click this link to hear the code?

If there isn’t a way to make the Flash object work with a screen reader, my fall-back is to use a clickable link and use JavaScript to play the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make Flash visible to screen readers.  One can do so using [flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/accessibility/AccessibilityProperties.html).

If you check the [Securimage GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage) the latest update has replaced `securimage_play.swf` with a version that exposes some accessibility information so the screen reader will read `Play Audio Captcha` when it detects the flash file.  It can now also be tabbed into focus from the form.

I didn't find much information on it, but I don't think that `Fangs` is able to show information from Flash movies embedded in webpages, but I confirmed that `JAWS` was able to detect the Securimage audio icon and read the message attached to it.

The [Securimage Flash Source Code](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage/tree/securimage_flash) is also now available on the GitHub repository so you are welcome to modify it to fit your needs as well.

Comment: Hi Drew, Thanks for the update. I've loaded the file and while I don't have the screen reader program JAWS loaded, I'm going to assume everything will work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to go with a solution that is expressly 508 compliant. I usually recommend reCaptcha: http://www.google.com/recaptcha.

Keep in mind, though, Captchas of all kinds are notorious for being terrible with true 508 compliance, and can be extremely annoying to all users. Though they're not as effective, honeypots can slow the wave of bots, and annoy fewer users. Personally, I go with annoying myself before I'll annoy my users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Flash is readable by screen readers. I'm afraid you don't have any other choice than using your failback solution...